# With Javascript, get the text of the particular <li> that was clicked

Tags: javascript

I have an input that generates Li elements when a button is clicked:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit"> Submit </button>

  <ul id ="list">

  </ul>
```

**JS**

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var listUl = document.getElementById("list");
  var listLi = document.createElement("li");
  var value = input.value;
  listUl.appendChild(listLi)
  listLi.textContent = value;
  gettingThisLi();
});
```

This is very straightforward, when clicking the submit button it creates an li, appends it to the ul and it gives it the input value. At the end of this function I call another function because I'm trying to figure out how to "get" that particular li when clicking on it. How to get it's text for example, or how to get it so I can just cross it when I click over it, etc...

So far I have this but every time I click on an li the whole list is printed.

```
function gettingThisLi(){
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li")
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  var listElement = lis[i];
  listElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(listElement)
  })}
  }
```

Comment: querySelectorAll selects all all the `li` elements. To make it work in this setup, pass the `li` as a parameter to the function. In your test setup, you can pass the element that you just created. In a later implementation, you can pass the element that was clicked from the click event handler that you need to bind to the li or any of its parents.

Comment: I suggest you refrain from using "input" and "submit" as an ID for an element to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are adding the same event twice on the li.

Explanation : when the first li is added , click event is added to this. Now when the next li is added and the list is iterated again. the click event get attached with first li again. This is why on first li click it will print 2 elements but on 2nd element still one. If you keep on adding li , click event will be attached with all the previous li's again.

Try this.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var listUl = document.getElementById("list");
  var listLi = document.createElement("li");
  var value = input.value;
  listUl.appendChild(listLi)
  listLi.textContent = value;
  gettingThisLi();
});

var print = function(){
  console.log(this.innerHTML)
  };



function gettingThisLi(){
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");


  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
   var listElement = lis[i];
   listElement.removeEventListener("click",print);
   listElement.addEventListener("click",print);
 }
  
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit"> Submit </button>

  <ul id ="list">

  </ul>
```

Comment: That's clever, to first remove it, and then to add it. I'll try it in a bit.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I cannot use ES6 right now, but I get that "lis.forEach" is not a function, I suspect that forEach is an Array method and cannot use it on "lis" since it's just an HTML Collection and not an Array, it may work after doing Arra.from(lis) first in ES6 but I cannot test that.

Comment: sorry for that but you need not to use for each same can be done will the loop as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using delegation and capturing the event in the `ul` element, then you can get the li element that triggered the event and the text of it.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var listUl = document.getElementById("list");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var listLi = document.createElement("li");
  var value = input.value;
  listUl.appendChild(listLi)
  listLi.textContent = value;
});

listUl.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log(target.innerText);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` selector in the click event. The following example prints the inner text of the clicked list item

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var listUl = document.getElementById("list");
  var listLi = document.createElement("li");
  var value = input.value;
  listUl.appendChild(listLi)
  listLi.textContent = value;
  listLi.onclick = gettingThisLi;
});


function gettingThisLi(){
    console.log(this.innerText)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit"> Submit </button>

  <ul id ="list">

  </ul>
```

Comment: This will have issues since this way also click event is getting attached again.

Comment: sorry. I didn't understand that. could you explain it a liitle bit more please

Comment: in you example add 2 li's and the click on the first li. it will print the text of first li twice. this is because the click event got attached twice with the first li element when you will add the second li.

Comment: oh. ok. could you give me some time to work on this. thank you

Comment: That's my main issue, I tried with this, but I get the issue you describe.

Comment: @Sergi    ok. Updated the code. try it now. If it works feel free to accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution:**
For instance, I have a list of items in HTML, and when any of this item is clicked will display it on the **h4** tag.

```
   <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
         <li>Item 4</li>
     </ul>
     <h4></h4>
```

Then in Js using a callback function with event listener will get specific element been clicked.

```
  const allItems= document.querySelectorAll('li');
  const display= document.querySelector('h4');
  allItems.forEach(item=>{

item.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
   display.innerText=event.target.textContent;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

don't need this function gettingThisLi()

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var listUl = document.getElementById("list");
  var listLi = document.createElement("li");
  var value = input.value;
  listUl.appendChild(listLi)
  listLi.textContent = value;
  listLi.addEventListener("click",print);
});

var print = function(){
  console.log(this.innerHTML)
  };
```